# Model texture flipped?

Tags: models

Im making a custom Wavefront .obj loader and the images loads but the texture is flipped. What is the problem? here is code and a image.

[image]

```
std::vector<UINT> vertexIndices, uvIndices, normalIndices;
std::vector<UINT> indices(4119);
std::vector< XMFLOAT3> temp_vertices;
std::vector< XMFLOAT2 > temp_uvs;
std::vector< XMFLOAT3 > temp_normals;
std::vector< XMFLOAT3> out_vertices;
std::vector< XMFLOAT3> out_normals;
std::vector< XMFLOAT2> out_uvs;
std::vector<Vertex::Basic32> vertices( 4119);
const char *path = "C:\\Users\\terry\\Desktop\\untitled.txt";


FILE * file = fopen(path, "r");
if( file == NULL ){
    printf("Impossible to open the file !\n");
    return;
}

while( 1 ){

    char lineHeader[128];
    // read the first word of the line
    int res = fscanf(file, "%s", lineHeader);
    if (res == EOF)
        break; // EOF = End Of File. Quit the loop.

    // else : parse lineHeader


    if ( strcmp( lineHeader, "v" ) == 0 ){
    XMFLOAT3 vertex;
    fscanf(file, "%f %f %f\n", &vertex.x, &vertex.y, &vertex.z );
    temp_vertices.push_back(vertex);
    }else if ( strcmp( lineHeader, "vt" ) == 0 ){
    XMFLOAT2 uv;
    fscanf(file, "%f %f\n", &uv.x, &uv.y );
    temp_uvs.push_back(uv);
    }else if ( strcmp( lineHeader, "vn" ) == 0 ){
    XMFLOAT3 normal;
    fscanf(file, "%f %f %f\n", &normal.x, &normal.y, &normal.z );
    temp_normals.push_back(normal);
    }else if ( strcmp( lineHeader, "f" ) == 0 ){
    std::string vertex1, vertex2, vertex3;
    unsigned int vertexIndex[3], uvIndex[3], normalIndex[3];
    int matches = fscanf(file, "%d/%d/%d %d/%d/%d %d/%d/%d\n", &vertexIndex[0], &uvIndex[0], &normalIndex[0], &vertexIndex[1], &uvIndex[1], &normalIndex[1], &vertexIndex[2], &uvIndex[2], &normalIndex[2] );
    if (matches != 9){
        printf("File can't be read by our simple parser : ( Try exporting with other options\n");
        return;
    }
    vertexIndices.push_back(vertexIndex[0]);
    vertexIndices.push_back(vertexIndex[1]);
    vertexIndices.push_back(vertexIndex[2]);
    uvIndices    .push_back(uvIndex[0]);
    uvIndices    .push_back(uvIndex[1]);
    uvIndices    .push_back(uvIndex[2]);
    normalIndices.push_back(normalIndex[0]);
    normalIndices.push_back(normalIndex[1]);
    normalIndices.push_back(normalIndex[2]);
    }
}



 for( unsigned int i=0; i<4119; i++ ){
     unsigned int vertexIndex = vertexIndices[i];
     XMFLOAT3 vertex = temp_vertices[ vertexIndex-1 ];
     out_vertices.push_back(vertex);
     unsigned int normalIndex = normalIndices[i];
     XMFLOAT3 normal = temp_normals[ normalIndex-1 ];
     out_normals.push_back(normal);
     unsigned int uvIndex = uvIndices[i];
     XMFLOAT2 uv = temp_uvs[ uvIndex-1 ];
     out_uvs.push_back(uv);

 }


 for( unsigned int i=0; i<4119; i++ ){
     vertices[i].Pos = out_vertices[i];
     vertices[i].Normal = out_normals[i];
     vertices[i].Tex = out_uvs[i];
     vertices[i].Tex.y = vertices[i].Tex.y * -1.0f;
     indices[i] = i;
 }
```

Comment: Im in Left handed coordinate system, DirectX

Comment: Having loaded in wavefront myself, I checked my loader code and I have  -- vp.SetTextureUV(result.Textures[TextureIndex].X, -result.Textures[TextureIndex].Y); -- which looks exactly what you are doing.  I assume you get the right result if you also negate the X texture coord?

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure Direct 3D flips the textures Y coordinates for you, so you don't need to do it yourself.